# Concurrent file parsing and inserting into Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I was playing with Go recently and come up with small script which parses log files and inserts them to elastic search. For each file I spawned a goroutine like this:

```
var wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(len(files))
for _, file := range files {
    go func(f os.FileInfo){
        defer wg.Done()
        ProcessFile(f.Name(), config.OriginFilePath, config.WorkingFilePath, config.ArchiveFilePath,fmt.Sprintf("http://%v:%v", config.ElasticSearch.Host, config.ElasticSearch.Port),config.ProviderIndex, config.NetworkData)
    }(file)
}
wg.Wait()
```

Inside of my processFile I have function which sends to elastic search:

```
func BulkInsert(lines []string, ES *elastic.Client) (*elastic.Response, error){
    r, err := ES.PerformRequest("POST", "/_bulk", url.Values{}, strings.Join(lines, "\n")+"\n")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return r, nil
}
```

The problem is that I don't fully understand how goroutines work. My understanding is that sending to elastic search is blocking one of my goroutines from executing. I tried spawning another goroutine for elastic search with bulk insert with same approach:

`WaitGroup`, `go func(){defer wg.Done(); BulkInsert(elems, ES);}()`
and `wg.Wait()` before my function return. However, I've discovered that in the end that not all my events end up in elastic search. I think this is due to goroutines returning without ever sending/waiting for bulk request to finish.

My question is, is my approach to this problem is correct? Can I achieve better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I achieve better performance?

unclear, it depends of the receiver and the sender capabilities.

> My question is, is my approach to this problem is correct?

might this help you better understand go routines,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    addr := "127.0.0.1:2074"

    srv := http.Server{
        Addr: addr,
        Handler: http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            log.Println("hit ", r.URL.String())
            <-time.After(time.Second)
            log.Println("done ", r.URL.String())
        }),
    }
    fail(unblock(srv.ListenAndServe))

    jobs := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

    // case 1
    // it creates 10 goroutines,
    // that triggers 10 // concurrent get queries
    {
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        wg.Add(len(jobs))
        log.Printf("starting %v jobs\n", len(jobs))
        for _, job := range jobs {
            go func(job int) {
                defer wg.Done()
                http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("http://%v/job/%v", addr, job))
            }(job)
        }
        wg.Wait()
        log.Printf("done %v jobs\n", len(jobs))
    }

    log.Println()
    log.Println("=================")
    log.Println()

    // case 2
    // it creates 3 goroutines,
    // that triggers 3 // concurrent get queries
    {
        wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
        wg.Add(len(jobs))
        in := make(chan string)
        limit := make(chan bool, 3)
        log.Printf("starting %v jobs\n", len(jobs))
        go func() {
            for url := range in {
                limit <- true
                go func(url string) {
                    defer wg.Done()
                    http.Get(url)
                    <-limit
                }(url)
            }
        }()
        for _, job := range jobs {
            in <- fmt.Sprintf("http://%v/job/%v", addr, job)
        }
        wg.Wait()
        log.Printf("done %v jobs\n", len(jobs))
    }

    log.Println()
    log.Println("=================")
    log.Println()

    // case 2: rewrite
    // it creates 6 goroutines,
    // that triggers 6 // concurrent get queries
    {
        wait, add := parallel(6)
        log.Printf("starting %v jobs\n", len(jobs))
        for _, job := range jobs {
            url := fmt.Sprintf("http://%v/job/%v", addr, job)
            add(func() {
                http.Get(url)
            })
        }
        wait()
        log.Printf("done %v jobs\n", len(jobs))
    }
}

func parallel(c int) (func(), func(block func())) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    in := make(chan func())
    limit := make(chan bool, c)
    go func() {
        for block := range in {
            limit <- true
            go func(block func()) {
                defer wg.Done()
                block()
                <-limit
            }(block)
        }
    }()
    return wg.Wait, func(block func()) {
        wg.Add(1)
        in <- block
    }
}

func unblock(block func() error) error {
    w := make(chan error)
    go func() { w <- block() }()
    select {
    case err := <-w:
        return err
    case <-time.After(time.Millisecond):
    }
    return nil
}

func fail(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

outputs

```
$ go run main.go 
2017/09/14 01:30:50 starting 10 jobs
2017/09/14 01:30:50 hit  /job/0
2017/09/14 01:30:50 hit  /job/4
2017/09/14 01:30:50 hit  /job/5
2017/09/14 01:30:50 hit  /job/2
2017/09/14 01:30:50 hit  /job/9
2017/09/14 01:30:50 hit  /job/1
2017/09/14 01:30:50 hit  /job/3
2017/09/14 01:30:50 hit  /job/7
2017/09/14 01:30:50 hit  /job/8
2017/09/14 01:30:50 hit  /job/6
2017/09/14 01:30:51 done  /job/5
2017/09/14 01:30:51 done  /job/4
2017/09/14 01:30:51 done  /job/2
2017/09/14 01:30:51 done  /job/0
2017/09/14 01:30:51 done  /job/6
2017/09/14 01:30:51 done  /job/9
2017/09/14 01:30:51 done  /job/1
2017/09/14 01:30:51 done  /job/3
2017/09/14 01:30:51 done  /job/7
2017/09/14 01:30:51 done  /job/8
2017/09/14 01:30:51 done 10 jobs
2017/09/14 01:30:51 
2017/09/14 01:30:51 =================
2017/09/14 01:30:51 
2017/09/14 01:30:51 starting 10 jobs
2017/09/14 01:30:51 hit  /job/0
2017/09/14 01:30:51 hit  /job/2
2017/09/14 01:30:51 hit  /job/1
2017/09/14 01:30:52 done  /job/2
2017/09/14 01:30:52 done  /job/0
2017/09/14 01:30:52 done  /job/1
2017/09/14 01:30:52 hit  /job/3
2017/09/14 01:30:52 hit  /job/4
2017/09/14 01:30:52 hit  /job/5
2017/09/14 01:30:53 done  /job/3
2017/09/14 01:30:53 done  /job/4
2017/09/14 01:30:53 done  /job/5
2017/09/14 01:30:53 hit  /job/6
2017/09/14 01:30:53 hit  /job/7
2017/09/14 01:30:53 hit  /job/8
2017/09/14 01:30:54 done  /job/6
2017/09/14 01:30:54 done  /job/7
2017/09/14 01:30:54 done  /job/8
2017/09/14 01:30:54 hit  /job/9
2017/09/14 01:30:55 done  /job/9
2017/09/14 01:30:55 done 10 jobs
2017/09/14 01:30:55 
2017/09/14 01:30:55 =================
2017/09/14 01:30:55 
2017/09/14 01:30:55 starting 10 jobs
2017/09/14 01:30:55 hit  /job/0
2017/09/14 01:30:55 hit  /job/1
2017/09/14 01:30:55 hit  /job/4
2017/09/14 01:30:55 hit  /job/2
2017/09/14 01:30:55 hit  /job/3
2017/09/14 01:30:55 hit  /job/5
2017/09/14 01:30:56 done  /job/0
2017/09/14 01:30:56 hit  /job/6
2017/09/14 01:30:56 done  /job/1
2017/09/14 01:30:56 done  /job/2
2017/09/14 01:30:56 done  /job/4
2017/09/14 01:30:56 hit  /job/7
2017/09/14 01:30:56 done  /job/3
2017/09/14 01:30:56 hit  /job/9
2017/09/14 01:30:56 hit  /job/8
2017/09/14 01:30:56 done  /job/5
2017/09/14 01:30:57 done  /job/6
2017/09/14 01:30:57 done  /job/7
2017/09/14 01:30:57 done  /job/9
2017/09/14 01:30:57 done  /job/8
2017/09/14 01:30:57 done 10 jobs
```

Comment: Thanks for example. As I understood, I need first example: I spawn as many goroutines as I need (dependings of length of `files` list length) and use same approach: `wg.Add(1)` and `wg.Wait()`. 


However I still don't understand, why does inner `wg` of elastic search bulk insert function doesn't block outer goroutine. I need to pass `wg` by reference in order to wait for `BulkInsert` function to return?

Comment: `wg` must not be copied, use a pointer if you need to pass it around. wg is not a channel, it does not organize the concurrency, it only tells when its all done, it blocks only on Wait() call. Can t really say about your specific bulk code without reading it.